# IIS with ARR as reverse proxy for ASP.NET WebAPI randomly escape newlines differently

Tags: iis, reverse-proxy, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, arr

We're running an asp.net Web API appliction in production, using IIS and ARR for SSL-offloading and reverse proxy. We're seeing some weird issues requesting xml from a webapi endpoint.

Randomly every now and then, it could be 2 seconds between requests, or minutes, it doesn't really matter, the output is transformed differently even though the database has not changed. It happens almost all the time, setting a cron-job to fetch one every minute, almost all responses end up differently.

One section of the response can have real newlines meanwhile the same content in the next response could escape them as "\n" thus outputting the text \n instead of having a real linebreak. This can be escaped differently also in different parts of the same response for the very same request. E.g. one xml-element could have real newlines, the next xml-element could have them escaped.

The web application uses the built-in .NET xmlwriter so there's no custom xml-outputting that occurs that would cause this.

I've cloned the virtual machine and setupped a staging environment where it's not reproducable, though the response here is much smaller due to less data.

Is there any setting in ARR that could cause the transform to behave like this on requests? E.g. some caching mechanism